# Marketing Cloud - Select MAX value from multiple columns

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

for each row I need to select highest value from 3 columns, somethings like below. However, for some reason I can't do this. Please help.

```SQL
SELECT 
SubscriberKey,
MAX(VALUE(Clicks_Syria), 
VALUE(Clicks_Ukraine), 
VALUE(Clicks_Afghanistan))
FROM Total_Clicks_Summary_V2_Copy
```

Comment: What error or result do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
SubscriberKey,
MAX(Clicks_Syria) as syria, 
MAX(Clicks_Ukraine) as ukraine, 
MAX(Clicks_Afghanistan) as afghanistan
FROM Total_Clicks_Summary_V2_Copy
GROUP BY SubscriberKey
```